# jquery rotate - multiple points

Tags: jquery, rotation

how do i make this plugin rotate as such: 
move 45 degrees, stop, move 45 *more* degrees, stop, etc.

the way it behaves by default is it moves 45 degrees and goes back to the beginning.

here is a basic continuous rotation

```
var rotation = function (){
   $("#img").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      callback: rotation
   });
}
rotation();
```

https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: i have this problem too. Do you have a solution now?#

Comment: store the degrees rotated in a variable and when rotating again rotate = new_rotate_angle + previous_rotate_angle